# Is Mavericks still available for download (from Apple or anywhere)?

Tags: macos

I've got a MBP (mid-2012) that is currently running Mountain Lion and I would like to upgrade it to Mavericks.  Now that Yosemite is available, it seems that Mavericks is no longer available for download.  Is that correct?  Is there any way to download a Mavericks installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mavericks does not currently appear in the Apple App Store. If you had "purchased" it before, it will appear in your Purchases view for download.

Registered Mac developers can also redeem a code to add Mavericks to their purchase view.

I don't think there are any other options from Apple.